# Grey tinge when viewing the animation in rendered view

Tags: animation

hey im quite new to animating, i was trying to make an animation of skullkid from majoras mask and when i go to render view it all appears to have a grey tint and barely any colour can someone please help me! i want it to look flat textured a bit. im trying to mimic the Zelda Majoras Mask 3d atmosphere

also if anybody has any tutorials that could help me out it would be great thanks!

[skullkid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8zVn.jpg)
also what happens if the transparent textures turn white in render? iv seen someone else do a video showing they had it but dont know how that fixed it

Comment: could you share an image

Comment: http://imgur.com/XciKXNZ here